# Converting list of years to double digits

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a table with a few hundred products on Access and I need to convert the years from the following format

```
1992,1993,1994,1995
```

to    `92-95`

A while back I learned from the forums how convert my years from 1992-1995 to how the format is now. But with recent requirements I now need another field with the first and last year from the field and double digits only. I was working with the function created a few weeks ago here but there are some parts I could not understand and came to the conclusion I can't use it for this case. Also some years are single such as "1984" which should show up like "84-84".

I'm not sure the previous function is usable but I'll add it in.

```
Public Function Conversion(ByVal pInput As Variant) As Variant
    Dim astrPieces() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim varReturn As Variant

    If pInput Like "####-####" Then
        astrPieces = Split(pInput, "-")
        lngFirst = CLng(astrPieces(0))
        lngLast = CLng(astrPieces(1))
        For i = lngFirst To lngLast
            varReturn = varReturn & "," & CStr(i)
        Next
        If Len(varReturn) > 0 Then
            varReturn = Mid(varReturn, 2)
        End If
    Else
        varReturn = pInput
    End If
    Conversion = varReturn
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they are in order this would word for multiple or single years;

```
Public Function ToShortYearSpan(ByVal pInput As Variant) As Variant
   ToShortYearSpan = Mid$(pInput, 3, 2) & "-" & Right$(pInput, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: thank you, I'm new so I apologize for the somewhat redundant question, but where do I add this? To the existing function I have or a new module entirely?

Comment: Add the above to wherever the current function is written

Comment: As a separate function (running two functions) ?

Comment: Paste it under the `end function` of the existing function (which is presumably in a Module (which can contain as many functions as you like))

Comment: thanks. ok I did that, when I did I would get a compile error running it in the immediate window "Expected: label or statement or end of statement" The `ToShortYearSpan = = Mid$(pInput, 3, 2) & "-" & Right$(pInput, 2)` is in red

Comment: Sorry typo, only one `=` delete the other

Comment: ok thanks for the quick reply, I didn't even catch that, I fixed it which got rid of the red letters, I still get the same issue. I'm typing `1992,1993,1994` in the immediate window for example and it gives me the error. Perhaps I'm testing it wrong in the immediate window?

Comment: So I wrote the function I posted above, then I added extra code you created (fixed the extra = as well), and in the Immediate Window I typed random years such as `1991,1992,1993` and I get the error: `Compile error: Expected: Label or statement or end of statement`

Comment: You need to tell it to run the function: `?ToShortYearSpan("1991,1992,1993")`

Comment: Wow, that was very simple. Sorry for the confusion, thank you very much it works perfectly.